Org-mode #+EXPORT_TITLE not working
Problem:
I have an org node with one tittle. I want to export the file to latex or pdf with a different title. The suggested #+EXPORT_TITLE is not working.
command used to export:
"C-c C-e l L"        or    "C-c C-e l o" (third input is l as in love, not I as in I'm)
both use Org Export Dispatcher
Things I tried:

putting :EXPORT_TITLE: in the PROPERTIES drawer
used #+LATEX_HEADER: \title{Proofie}
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [title=Proofie]
\title{Proofie} in the content
removed the #+SETUPFILE
Different org files
#+OPTIONS: title:nil

my .org file:
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       dea62e1a-4616-4f5c-820f-249d24de4fec
:END:
#+EXPORT_TITLE: Proofie
#+TITLE: rp coarse geometry
#+AUTHOR: My name
#+Commment: setupfile is for LaTeX
#+SETUPFILE: template.org



* Proof

#+attr_latex: :options {}\label{}
#+begin_prop
  Let $\{ (X_{n}, d_{n})\}$ be a sequence of finite graphs with the...
#+end_prop


EXPORT_TITLE is only used when you are exporting a subtree (go into the export dispatcher and press C-s to change the scope to subtree before you use l o). Then you can add the property to the subtree and it will be used as the title when you export the subtree. Also note that EXPORT_TITLE is not a keyword, it is a property, so you cannot use #+EXPORT_TITLE[1].
So the simplest way to write your file is to do this:
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       dea62e1a-4616-4f5c-820f-249d24de4fec
:END:

#+TITLE: rp coarse geometry
#+AUTHOR: My name
#+Commment: setupfile is for LaTeX
#+SETUPFILE: template.org



* Proof
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_TITLE: Proofie
:END:
#+attr_latex: :options {}\label{}
#+begin_prop
  Let $\{ (X_{n}, d_{n})\}$ be a sequence of finite graphs with the...
#+end_prop

and just export the subtree: with the cursor on the Proof headline, do C-c C-e C-s l o. And you are done.

If you want to define the property at the top level, then you need to arrange property inheritance to allow the subtree to pick it up.
The property is obtained like this in ox.el:
     (org-entry-get (point) "EXPORT_TITLE" 'selective)

That selective says: "Use inheritance to get the value of this property but only if the variable org-use-property-inheritance says to do so".
See the relevant doc strings: C-h f org-entry-get and C-h v org-use-property-inheritance for explanation.
To enable inheritance for EXPORT_TITLE, you can set org-use-property-inheritance to t (but if you do a lot of property searches, that will slow things down), or you can set it to a list of properties, in which case only those properties will be inherited.
So add this to your init file:
(setq org-use-property-inheritance '("EXPORT_TITLE"))

and restart your emacs (OR you can add this definition as a local file variable to your file - that's what I do in the modified example below).
Here's your example, modified to add EXPORT_TITLE as a property to the top level property drawer and to add a file-local redefinition to org-use-property-inheritance (file-local variables are an Emacs customization feature, described in the Local variables in files section of the Emacs manual):
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       dea62e1a-4616-4f5c-820f-249d24de4fec
:EXPORT_TITLE: Proofie
:END:
#+TITLE: rp coarse geometry
#+AUTHOR: My name
#+Commment: setupfile is for LaTeX
#+SETUPFILE: template.org



* Proof

#+attr_latex: :options {}\label{}
#+begin_prop
  Let $\{ (X_{n}, d_{n})\}$ be a sequence of finite graphs with the...
#+end_prop



* Local variable                                                         :noexport:
# Local variables:
# org-use-property-inheritance: ("EXPORT_TITLE")
# End:


Exporting the Proof subtree (by putting point somewhere in the subtree and then using C-c C-e C-s l o) will then use the value of EXPORT_TITLE.

Footnotes
[1] Do C-h v org-option-keywords and C-h v org-default-properties: EXPORT_TITLE does not appear in the keywords list, but it does appear in the properties list.

I just figured out:
If I Put
#+OPTIONS: title:nil
at the top and then
#+BEGIN_EXPORT latex
\title{New tittle}
\maketitle
#+END_EXPORT

just below the org file settings then I get the desired result.
But this is hacky and the latex file contains two \title{} entries, I would prefer to get #+EXPORT_TITLE: to work properly (or #+LATEX_TITLE if that is a thing) if anyone can help with that I would appreciate it!
